# flex mx line chart datafunction

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, linechart

I have a JSON service link that returns month as an `Integer` and a price as a    `Number` which I display on an `<mx:Linechart />`.

Now, I don't want to display the month as an `Integer` instead as the string equivalent of the month value.

I have tried to create a datafunction like so

```
public function myDataFunction(series:LineSeries, item:Object, fieldName:String):Object {
    var months:Array = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var my_date:Date = new Date();

    if (fieldName == 'yValue')
        return(item.price);
    else if (fieldName == "xValue")
    {
        return((months[my_date.month]));
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

I would like to post reputations but i don't have enough reputations.
Anybody please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you need to display month names in horizontal axis, but you get numbers?

Comment: Well i have already delivered app although i couldn't solve that problem. But that was exactly what i wanted to do. Thanks for the response. I can still learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show months names in the horizontal axis, you need to assign `labelFunction` to it.

When declaring line chart, you specify horizontal axis like this:

```
<mx:Linechart>
     <mx:horizontalAxis>
         <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="xValue"/>
     </mx:horizontalAxis>
</mx:Linechart>
```

To modify values of horizontal axis, you need to specify `labelFunction`:

```
<mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="xValue" labelFunction="labelFunction"/>
```

`labelFunction` should look like this:

```
function labelFunction(categoryValue:Object, previousCategoryValue:Object, axis:CategoryAxis, categoryItem:Object):String {
    return "label";
}
```

For more info see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/CategoryAxis.html#labelFunction